# Check custom audience email list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am using facebook/php-ads-sdk: 2.5.*

I created new custom audience using SDK.
Then manually added user by emails.

Then I check my custom audience list
And checked Audience History
which seems fine to me
[My recent audience history](http://screencast.com/t/5WDbJw7DZ)

but

That shows me [Audience is not available](http://screencast.com/t/tJVo1vqB9)
which suggest me that

> Audiences must include at least 20 people to be used for ads.

So I added 20 user manually
Still Facebook showing me this list is not available for same reason.

How can I check the list of user?
What did I miss?

When I use graph api explorer it shows me

> (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action

And by using php sdk I can read only approximate count which is 20 already.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the audience does not have more than 20 people in it, as not 100% of your email addresses matched users. Unfortunately you cannot know which ones did and did not match.

You can check the approximate count in the audience by doing:

```
$audience = new CustomAudience($id);
$audience->read(array(CustomAudienceFields::APPROXIMATE_COUNT));
echo $audience->{CustomAudienceFields::APPROXIMATE_COUNT};
```

Comment: Thank you paul, Unfortunately approximate count is **20**

Comment: in that case, the audience is too small. The minimum approximate number we show is 20 I believe. You should always aim for greater numbers where possible as 20 is still very small for an audience.

Comment: Thank you paul I will check try increasing email numbers